# Include a Local Perl Module that References a Local C Library

Tags: c, perl, wrapper, portability, suffix-tree

I want to include a local module in a Perl script that's not installed. The code below seems to work for that purpose. However, the module I want to include is a wrapper for a C library. I do it as follows:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/gray-tree-suffix-59e1c06/lib";
use Tree::Suffix;
```

The Perl module is called [Tree::Suffix](https://github.com/gray/tree-suffix) and acts as a wrapper for [libstree](http://www.icir.org/christian/libstree/). My question is, how do I reference the C library locally as well (given that it's not installed).

I presume it would have something to do with the inner workings of the Perl module? I apologise if this is an amateurish question. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand.  If the library isn't installed, you cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this :

say the `.so` file is `foo.so`, and its full path is `/bar/baz/foo.so`:

```
BEGIN
{
  $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} = '/bar/baz:'.$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH};
}

use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/gray-tree-suffix-59e1c06/lib";
use Tree::Suffix;
```

or, alternatively, change the shell's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before your Perl program is called :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/bar/baz:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
[run your program]
```